# Comparing two dates in Oracle after using TO_DATE function

Tags: sql, oracle, date, where-clause

I have the following Oracle Query that is converting todays date and the date field from the table into the same format. However, when trying to compare the two they aren't coming up as equal.

```
CAST(dstamp As Date), TO_DATE(CURRENT_DATE,'dd-MON-YY HH24.MI.SS','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American')
```

The cast is used on the field in my table, both these return.

[image]

However, when adding the following where statement no rows are returned. I can't work out why these wouldn't be classed as equal?

```
WHERE CAST(dstamp As Date) = TO_DATE(CURRENT_DATE,'dd-MON-YY HH24.MI.SS','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American');
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `CURRENT_DATE` returns a `DATE` value. **Never** run  `TO_DATE` on a value which is already a DATE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date is ALREADY a date.  You don't need to convert it.  You may need to remove the time component.  Does this do what you want?

```
WHERE TRUNC(dstamp) = TRUNC(sysdate)
```

Comment: Talk about over complicating things! This works thank you

Comment: Oracle would not use an index on the `dstamp` column if you compare `TRUNC(dstamp) = TRUNC(sysdate)`; if you did want to use an index, you would need to create a function-based index on `TRUNC(dstamp)`.

Comment: @MT0 . . . I thought about mentioning that, but the OP's original code is not index safe either.  Plus, Oracle supports function based indexes, so it is possible that there is an index that includes `trunc(dstamp)`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to check if `dstamp` belongs to the current day, I would suggest:

```
where dstamp >= trunc(sysdate) and dstamp < trunc(sysdate) + 1
```

Athough a bit more verbose, this will be more efficient than applying a date function on the column being compared. Using a function on a column in a predicate makes the query non-SARGable, ie it cannot take advantage of an existing index.

Comment: Thank you, this also works I was massively overcomplicating it!